# Spectral radius of matrix after column scaling

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces, spectral-graph-theory

Given an $nxn$ real matrix $A$ and a diagonal matrix $D=(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$, with each $d_i<1$. I would like to show that the spectral radius of $A\cdot D$ strictly decreases. That is, $\rho(A\cdot D) < \rho(A)$. Does this hold in general? If not, does it hold when $A$ is symmetric and has spectral radius $1$ ($\rho(A)=1$)? In fact, the $A$ for which I need the result is the Laplacian of the complete graph $K_n$.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably $A\ne0$ and $0\le d_i<1$ for each $i$. Then $\rho(AD)<\rho(A)$. This is true not only when $A$ is Laplacian, but also for every nonzero Hermitian matrix $A$, for, if $d=\frac{1+\max_i\sqrt{d_i}}2$, then $\|x\|>d\|x\|>\max_id_i\|x\|\ge\|Dx\|$ for every nonzero $x$ and hence
$$
\begin{align*}
\rho(A)
>d^2\rho(A)
&=d^2\max_{\|x\|\le1}\|Ax\|\\
&=d\max_{\|y\|\le d}\|Ay\|\\
&\ge d\max_{\|z\|\le1}\|AD^{1/2}z\|\\
&\ge\max_{\|z\|\le1}\|D^{1/2}AD^{1/2}z\|\\
&=\rho(D^{1/2}AD^{1/2})\\
&=\rho(AD).
\end{align*}
$$
If $A$ is not Hermitian, the inequality does not hold in general. E.g. when
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&-1}
$$
and $D$ has two distinct positive entries, $\rho(A)=0<\rho(AD)$ because $A$ is nilpotent but $AD$ is not.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the following identity: $\rho(AD)=\rho(D^{1/2}AD^{1/2})$? Thanks.

Comment: Inspired by your answer, why not simply use $\rho(AD) \leq \|A\| \|D\|$ and since $A$ is Hermitian, $\| A\|=\rho(A)$ for the induced $2$-norm. Then, it only remains to show that under this norm $\| D\|<=d$ where $d=\max\{ d_i\mid i\in[1,n]\}$. The latter holds: $$\| D\|=\max_{\|z\|=1} \|Dz\|_2\leq d \max_{\|z\|=1}\|z\|_2=d$$.

Comment: @Sirolf That's because $\rho(XY)=\rho(YX)$ in general. Anyway, your proof is definitely better.